# Which Option is more expensive?

Tags: finance

Consider two European put options, written on the same asset, with the same maturity, but different strike prices: K1< K2

Which option is more expensive?

Then Answer the same question, but using call options instead.

It made sense to me that a put option - a sell option, with a higher strike price, would be worth more, hence is more expensive. And a call option - a buy option, with a higher strike price would be bought for more, so again is worth more and is more expensive? Or is that completely wrong?

Comment: Think about what a call at strike $K$ is.  It's the right to pay $K$ for the asset at some future time.  Would you prefer to pay a lot for the asset or would you prefer to pay less?

Comment: @Lulu, so i would want to buy for less, and because the demand would be for a lower price, the lower strike would have greater value. yeah?

Comment: That is correct.  Another way to say the same thing;  in all scenarios the call with the lower strike gives a greater or equal payout, hence it must cost more.

Comment: @Lulu, thanks, that's cleared it up for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A European *put* option gives you the right to *sell* an underlying asset at a certain price (the strike price) at a certain time (the expiry date). You would want to sell an asset at a higher price. Therefore the put option with a higher strike price would be more expensive, all other things being equal.

A European *call* option gives you the right to *buy* an underlying asset at a certain price (the strike price) at a certain time (the expiry date). You would want to buy an asset at a lower price. Therefore the call option with a lower strike price would be more expensive, all other things being equal.

Comment: @Andy Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my take:
for a call, we are looking at Spot----L----H (we move from spot to higher strike, in that order), where L and H are lower and higher strikes.
The probability of hitting L is higher than hitting H and thus call with lower strikes are quoted higher.

For put, we have L---H---Spot. The probability of hitting H is higher and thus puts with higher strikes are priced higher.

We have to think of which direction on x-axis (the price) we are moving and how that is going to impact the call or put.